# Is there a shorter way I can create this list?

Tags: python, list, scipy

Here's the tuple I obtained when I'm trying to dins the peak of some result:

```
In:  peaks, _ = find_peaks(probsuc,width=4)
     peak_prominences(probsuc, peaks, wlen=7)
Out: (array([0.015625  , 0.24166667]), array([ 9, 36]), array([14, 42]))
```

I just want to obtain two lists: `[9,14]` and `[36,42]`. What I did was

```
In:  [peak_prominences(probsuc, peaks, wlen=7)[1][0],peak_prominences(probsuc, peaks, wlen=7)[2][0]]
Out: [9, 14]
```

Is there a shorter way I can obtain the same result? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed avoid calling `peak_prominences` twice.

For instance:

```
[arr[0] for arr in peak_prominences(probsuc, peaks, wlen=7)[1:]]
```

Or:

```
next(zip(*peak_prominences(probsuc, peaks, wlen=7)[1:]))
```

The latter is a tuple instead of a list. If you need a list, then apply `list()` to it.